# How to make a relative positioned element not affect layout?

Tags: html, css

I have two relatively positioned elements that are next to each other. They both have text.
The `display` of these 2 elements is `inline-block`, so the result looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXwqH.png)
I am trying to make these two elements show in the same exact place, so that "Pro" overlaps "Free". I know that is achievable if I position the two elements absolutely, and not relatively. In my case, I am trying to create an animation and positioning the elements absolutely will be problematic, because I want the `top` and `left` of the elements to be 0 (I am trying to create an animation). I am also using bootstrap if that helps...

I've tried doing some searching but I still wasn't able to find anything useful. No one had the same error as me and I wasn't able to find anything useful in my case.

I also need this to work on other devices with different viewport widths and heights, so I can't just move the text 10 pixels to the left.

Here is the code:

```css
.direction {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.direction p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
      <div class="direction" id="webDiv">
        <p>Pro</p>
      </div>
      <div class="direction" id="codeDiv">
        <p>Free</p>
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use position:absolute and rely on transform instead of top/left

Comment: @Temani Afif But then how can I make it work on all devices & viewports? I wouldn't want a user with a smaller display to have the text uncentred.

Comment: Just an observation: the center tag is deprecated. More modern methods like flex/grid can help centering things. I don't understand why absolute positioning is ruled out because of an animation requirement. Perhaps you could show us what animation you want to do?

Comment: I know the center tag is deprecated, but I was desperate and I wanted to make it work in any way. I had tried fixing this for the whole day. I don't want absolute positioning, because it automatically positions relatively to its body (or nearest positioned ancestor). This is already problematic: https://snipboard.io/Z5MtUn.jpg It doesn't position in the center. I'd have to deal with that using JavaScript (which could be slow and hard, since I'd be fighting with how html and css work). If I somehow manage to position them in the center, there will still be a problem.

Comment: The animation/transition I'm creating consists of this: I will have two divs, with one never being on the screen, and the other being in the center. The user will be able to press arrows to switch between them. Here's how I'm planning to achieve this: when the user presses an arrow, the left: position of each of these divs will be reset and set to a value that will show the one that was previously hidden and hide the one that was previously shown. I call it an animation because it's a transition, sorry if that's not the right name for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid:

```css
.direction {
  grid-area:1/1; /* they will overlap */
  position: relative;
}

.direction p {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: right;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-content:center; /* and placed at the center */
}
```

```html
<div class="direction" id="webDiv">
  <p>Pro</p>
</div>
<div class="direction" id="codeDiv">
  <p>Free</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. This technically works, but it's not perfect, as I want "Pro" to be in the center of "free". Right now, "Pro" is around 20 pixels away from the center. This is important to me because the direction div will have a lot more text and it will have to be positioned very well to look good.

Comment: @IMPixel adjust the text-align, you set it to be right. make it center

Comment: Okay I ran into an error after trying this. I'm using bootstrap and I'm guessing the display:grid kind of ruined the whole page (I'm running this all in one file with other elements)

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to my own question, it wasn't exactly what I expected to do but it works and it doesn't mess with the transition I'm trying to create. I just set the width of direction to 100vw and it's position to absolute. The divs still weren't in the center, they were exactly 50vw away from the center.
I set the left-margin of the divs to -50vw.